# global.asax.cs authorize events for webapi need lock?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, global-asax

I am working on a web api and each request is authenticated with Authorize annotation on methods i.e. [Authorize (roles="trader")]

Based on the logs I can tell that multiple requests are entering the Application_PostAcquireRequestState event simultaneously.

As roles are loaded in Application_PostAcquireRequestState event, there can be race condition and some of the calls fail randomly.

I am not sure if I am on right track. The event is application level and Application.Lock() may fix the issue and like to know if it is the correct solution. 
I have noticed a couple of calls to the web api failed, which were originated simultaneously.

I appreciate your help.

Global.ascs.cs

```
 protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState()
 {
//Application.Lock();
//get user roles and verify access...
...
//Application.Unlock();
}
```

controller.cs

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Trader")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrder(long id)
{
    //get order
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong, this event, as well as a bunch of others (BeginRequest, AuthenticateRequest, AcquireRequestState etc.) is technically an application-level event (`Application_...`), however, actually it is a request-level event and multiple copies of the same handler are fired concurrently for different requests.

This means that the `sender` argument of the handler gives you exact execution context and is intended to be used like

```
protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext ctx = app.Context; // current context

    // with the current context in hand you can pretty much access anything
    // including the Request, Response and last but not least, User
}
```

No need for locking or any other means of throttling.

I am only not sure why would you verify the access here, considering the MVC/WebAPI will do it in a moment in the pipeline, based on the `Authorize` and roles you put there.

Comment: this webapi used in windows service, which trigger based on message in message queue. IOW, call the web api for each message. as it is service, the user is same in this case, the api can be used in application later on.

Comment: Whatever you say, the answer is still valid.

Comment: I get your point and thank you for your help. There are multiple simultaneous calls to this message and it is possible to have race condition. This is application level event and to sync the calls, Application.Lock might help.The event is raised for every webapi request. It is difficult to debug as only ~1% of the calls are failing.

Comment: There should be no race condition. Each call has its own `context.User` and should update its own copy. Even if multiple requests are processed concurrently, they do not interfere. If there is something wrong, it is they way you acquire roles, this is where your actual issue might be.